# How to block GitHub pull request when Jira ticket is not present

Tags: github, jira

At my previous job a pull request in Github was only allowed to be merged if the new branch, the pull request title, and all of the commits had a Jira ticket number in the title.

I was sure that it was something trivial. However, I cannot figure out how to do it.

Did anyone implement something similar?

Comment: Maybe this was managed via githooks?

Comment: There are many hooks, plugins and integrations for git[hub] and Jira, I'd suggest some research. For example: https://blog.github.com/2018-10-04-announcing-the-new-github-and-jira-software-cloud-integration/

Answer (score -1):

You can implement a simple protection using name pattern for the new branch you are creating.

You can read about it here:
[managing-a-branch-protection-rule](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule)